# How can I call a part of an element from a list in Mathematica?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm doing some image processing in Mathematica (as homework). I'm working with this sort of list:

```
{ 1 -> {0.0125858, 0.068223, 0.000278799}, 
  2 -> {0.174, 0.304475, 0.126911}, 
  3 -> {0.0160498, 0.0752313, 0.0005017}, 
  4 -> {0.040932, 0.14199, 0.00293246}, 
  5 -> {0.0154049, 0.0714337, 0.000877047}, 
  6 -> {0.0124556, 0.0525255, 0.000437179}, 
  7 -> {0.32205, 0.518331, 0.169125} }
```

I want to be able to access the bracketed sub-lists (sans arrow) and divide the elements by a certain number.

For example, if I call this list "x", then typing "x[[1]]" returns

```
1 -> {0.0125858, 0.068223, 0.000278799}
```

whereas I need to isolate

```
{0.0125858, 0.068223, 0.000278799}
```

Is there a command that can do this for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got your image expressed as a list of replacement rules.  Extracting the coordinates of point `1` is very simple:

```
In[3]:=    1 /. img
Out[3]:=   {0.0125858, 0.068223, 0.000278799}
```

where `/.` is the common idiom for the function `ReplaceAll`.  The documentation will explain exactly what's going on.

Comment: Perfect... Is there anyway to add the "1 -> " to the first element after I do the appropriate operation?

Comment: If you've got another question ask another question, if you want to edit your existing question edit it.  Whatever you do don't expect answers to questions asked in comments.  There's just not enough room or formatting available.

Comment: `Rule[#, # /. img] &@1`

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, you can reference the right hand side of your rules using a a direct `Part` specification:

```
     data = { a -> {0.0125858, 0.068223, 0.000278799}, 
              b -> {0.174, 0.304475, 0.126911} }

     data[[1,2]] -> {0.0125858, 0.068223, 0.000278799}
     data[[2,1]] -> b
```

Mark's answer is the usual way of working, but it is handy to know the part notation `[[]]` works with things other than lists.

The question I think you are after in your comment is a good example: suppose you want to operate on the right hand side, leaving the left alone, you can do something like this:

```
     data[[2, 2]] = 10 data[[2, 2]];

     data -> {a -> {0.0125858, 0.068223, 0.000278799},
              b -> {1.74, 3.04475, 1.26911}}
```